# Javascript newbie function doubts

Tags: javascript, function

I am learning some javascript and I never got the idea of what is the difference between creating a function like this:

```
var justMe = function(param1, param2) {
     code code code;
};
```

And this:

```
function justMe(param1, param2) {
    code code code;
}
```

And why in the second example is the semi-colon is not requiered at the end, like in the first example?

Comment: *"And why in the second example is the semi-colon is not requiered at the end, like in the first example?"*: In the first case you have an expression statement (an assignment expression to be precise), which always has to end with a semicolon. In the second case you have a function declaration, which does not.

Comment: This is the way to Create a JavaScript Function

    function justMe(param1, param2) {
        code code code;
    }

But this

You assigned set of these String JustMe variable.

var justMe = function(param1, param2) {
     code code code;
};

try this sample


    var justMe = function(param1, param2) {
         return param1 + param2;
    };
    
    alert(justMe);

then you Get complete String inside justMe.

**DEMO**  [Link][1]


  [1]: http://jsfiddle.net/9tcSc/

Answer (score 0):

I'll give it simply.

```
function justMe(param1, param2) {
    code code code;
}
```

Here you are declaring the function in it's original syntax.

```
var justMe = function(param1, param2) {
     code code code;
};
```

Here you are assigning a function body to a variable and hence you require the end semicolon.

Comment: @SriHarshaChilakapati Please do not ask people to accept/vote for your answers.